# DRF, return serialized data after update object in the view

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have the following view with custom create method that can post or patch data:

```py
class MonthsViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        # TODO: Workaround until Auth is setup on the front.
        query_set = Month.objects.all() if isinstance(self.request.user, AnonymousUser) \
            else Month.objects.filter(farm__user=self.request.user)
        return query_set

    serializer_class = MonthSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request_month = request.data['month']
        year = request.data['year']
        farm = request.data['farm']
        days = request.data['days']
        # TODO: understand why built-in update_or_create didn't work here.
        farm_obj = Farm.objects.get(id=farm)
        try:
            month = Month.objects.get(year=year, month=request_month, farm=farm_obj)
            month.days = days
            month.save()
            serializer = MonthSerializer(data=month, many=False, partial=True)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Month.DoesNotExist:
            Month.objects.create(year=year, month=request_month, farm=farm_obj, days=days)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)`
```

Now my problem is sending back the object's data after updating, the update is successful but I can't serialize that object after saving it and sending it back in the response when a request to update a month comes in, it gets updated but the response is this error:

```
400
Error: Bad Request
[
  {
    "non_field_errors": [
      "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got Month."
    ]
  }
]
```

My serializer:

```py
class MonthSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Month
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: issue in `MonthSerializer(data=month,....)` DRF expects a dict like object in `data` argument

Comment: @ArakkalAbu a dict containing the object like {'data':month} or a dict containing the fields  of the object?

Answer (score 1):

Please can you share your request content and your model .

In your Json request i think you are trying to send a Month Object but the serializer is waiting for dict .

maybe your json request should be :

"month":[ {your month object} ]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by doing the following and based on the answer by Arakkal Abu.

```py
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request_month = request.data['month']
        year = request.data['year']
        farm = request.data['farm']
        days = request.data['days']
        farm_obj = Farm.objects.get(id=farm)
        try:
            month = Month.objects.get(year=year, month=request_month, farm=farm_obj)
            month.days = days
            month.save()
            data = {'month': month.month, 'year': month.year, 'date': month.date,
                    'farm': month.farm, 'days': month.days}
            serializer = MonthSerializer(data=data, many=False)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Month.DoesNotExist:
            month = Month.objects.create(year=year, month=request_month, farm=farm_obj, days=days)
            data = {'month': month.month, 'year': month.year, 'date': month.date,
                    'farm': month.farm, 'days': month.days}
            serializer = MonthSerializer(data=data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This code works but it seems rather odd to me.